# Hardening user's role after add_role

Tags: user-roles

Using an instance of WP_User ($user) obtained via get_user_by(), I use
`$user->add_role('custom-role')`
to modify the user's role(s), then
`wp_update_user($user)`
to store the changed user in the database.

This doesn't seem to work. The update is lost on a refresh of the web page.

I could update *prefix*_capabilities in usermeta, but that seems a backdoor approach.

Is there a better way to programatically change a user's role, and have it be retained?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `wp_update_user` after calling `add_role`. `add_role` is already persistent and updates the user meta directly. Are you sure you're not accidentally undoing that by calling `wp_update_user`. How are you calling `wp_update_user`?

Comment: You're right. I was over-thinking it. WP_User->add_role() is already persistent. I screwed it up by adding the wp_update_user(). Removing it fix the problem. Thanks for your response.